Blink the on board LED with bare metal - Raspberry Pi 3B
I'm trying to blink the green led that shows sd card activity on my Raspberry PI 3B board, using bare metal code and rust.
What I have done so far :

I've read that the on board led for sd card activity is hardwired to GPIO 16 (https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=12530)

In my code, I set the GPIO 16 to be an output:


// Set pin 16 to output mode
let mut reg = GPIO_GPFSEL1.read_volatile();
reg &= !(0b111 << 18); // Clear bits 18-20
reg |= 0b001 << 18; // Set bits 18-20 to output mode
GPIO_GPFSEL1.write_volatile(reg);


I then loop and se / unset the pin output value

GPIO_GPSET0.write_volatile(1 << LED_PIN);
// ...
GPIO_GPCLR0.write_volatile(1 << LED_PIN);


My constants are defined according to the manual for the BCM2837 (https://cs140e.sergio.bz/docs/BCM2837-ARM-Peripherals.pdf):

const GPIO_GPFSEL1: *mut u32 = (0x3F20_0004) as *mut u32;
const GPIO_GPSET0: *mut u32 = (0x3F20_001C) as *mut u32;
const GPIO_GPCLR0: *mut u32 = (0x3F20_0028) as *mut u32;
// GPIO pin number for the onboard LED
const LED_PIN: u32 = 16;


I compile to arm architecture, and using a linker to align the start of the code to the 0x8000 address. Here is the objdump -D view of the top:

Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:       e24dd058        sub     sp, sp, #88     @ 0x58
    8004:       e3001004        movw    r1, #4
    8008:       e3431f20        movt    r1, #16160      @ 0x3f20
    800c:       e58d1034        str     r1, [sp, #52]   @ 0x34
    8010:       e58d1038        str     r1, [sp, #56]   @ 0x38
    8014:       e5910000        ldr     r0, [r1]
    8018:       e58d003c        str     r0, [sp, #60]   @ 0x3c
    801c:       e59d003c        ldr     r0, [sp, #60]   @ 0x3c
    8020:       e58d0000        str     r0, [sp]
    ....


Then I use arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary target/armv7a-none-eabi/debug/blinking_led target/binary/kernel7.img to convert the elf file to flat binary

I then format my sd card to fat32, copy on to it the flat binary as well as the following files from the rpi formware repo (https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware) :


bootcode.bin
fixup.dat
start.elf
(and kernel7.img)

After all this, I plug the sd card in my raspberry, power it on, the green light turns on (indicate sd card activity) for a second, and turns off. No blinking.
I find it pretty hard to debug bare metal code (that's why I wanted to make a small working example before doing more complicated things) so I have no clue what is going on on the board. So I'm asking for help, maybe someone with better knowledge will spot my mistakes.
I understand It's really hard to tell what may be wrong, so I can do my best to provide additional info if needed. I only have a raspberry board on the hardware part, so I can't try the led using another GPIO (that's why I wanted to try to turn on the on board led).

"My constants are defined according to the manual for the BCM2837 ..." - Your specifications of 0x3F20_XXXX does not match any addresses mentioned in that document. Rather the doc mentions 0x7E20xxxx as the physical address range for the GPIO peripheral.

@sawdust It is explained in the documentation that the addresses at 0x7E are actually mapped to 0x3F: "Thus a peripheral advertised here at bus address 0x7Ennnnnn is
available at physical address 0x3Fnnnnnn." (section 1.2.3)

How did you program the MMU? I think you need at bare minimum to set 1:1 mapping before doing anything like this.

Also do you have memory barriers in place?

@Oandry sorry for the late reply, I have not touched the MMU at all, nor have I used memory barriers. Are those steps required for the most basic, unsafe example ? I haven't heard of those before.
